# Confidence interval endpoints

Tags: statistics

The left endpoint of the confidence interval is $28.4$, and the right endpoint of the confidence interval is $40.4$. Find the margin of error.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely to get an answer if you show that you made some effort yourself.

Comment: You should give some indication of what you've done on the problem and where you're stuck. Here you need to know the definition of margin of error. If you do not know and cannot find it or are confused about what it says, then that should be indicated in your question. If you know it but aren't sure how to apply it (which seems less likely here) then that should be said in the question as well

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have no work shown, I'll assume you're new to statistics. First, I recommend you do some research on confidence intervals, margin of error, and the relationship between the two. [Here](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/introductory-concepts/confidence-interval/confidence-interval/) is good place to get a VERY brief overview of these concepts. You will find that the link I've provided should supply you with an example identical to the question you've asked. I recommend you review these concepts more thoroughly in your text book or online, the link I provided does not suffice as a replacement.

**Confidence Intervals:** "A confidence interval is a range of values, derived from sample statistics, that is likely to contain the value of an unknown population parameter."

**Margin of Error:** "When you use statistics to estimate a value, it's important to remember that no matter how well your study is designed, your estimate is subject to random sampling error. The margin of error quantifies this error and indicates the precision of your estimate."

"For a two-sided confidence interval, the margin of error is the distance from the estimated statistic to each confidence interval value. When a confidence interval is symmetric, the margin of error is half of the width of the confidence interval."

Thus, the relationship between margin of error and confidence intervals for this particular situation can be described by *ME $=\frac{(b-a)}{2}, $* given that the confidence interval is (a, b).